# How to retrieve data from Python Dataframe that has multiple layers of headers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file in the following format:

```
            Level1_head1    Level1_head2    Level1_head3
            Level2_head1    Level2_head2    Level2_head3 
ID
S0000001    someValue       someValue       someValue       
S0000002    someValue       someValue       someValue       
S0000003    someValue       someValue       someValue       
S0000004    someValue       someValue       someValue       
S0000005    someValue       someValue       someValue
```

Please note that the cells above `ID` are empty and cells that on the right hand side of `ID` are empty too.

I've put above data in a Python Dataframe object `df`, and tried to pull column `ID` from it:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=[0,1], index_col=0)
date_series = df[0:]
```

However, I've got the whole dataframe instead of single column. When output the dataframe, it is displayed as following:

```
            Level2_head1    Level2_head2    Level2_head3 
ID
S0000001    someValue       someValue       someValue       
S0000002    someValue       someValue       someValue       
S0000003    someValue       someValue       someValue       
S0000004    someValue       someValue       someValue       
S0000005    someValue       someValue       someValue
```

I've also tried:

```
date_series = df['ID']
```

And

```
date_series = df.ID
```

However, for the former, I've got a key error that `df` cannot find a key whose value is 'ID'. For the latter, I've got an error says that `df` has no attribute 'ID'.

I'm totally confused now. How can I retrieve the first column (ID) that contains the IDs?

Answer (score 0):

You cant use `date_series = df['ID']`, because `ID` is `name` of `index`.

But using [`index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html) get first column `index` to `Series`:

```
print df
         Level1_head1 Level1_head2 Level1_head3
         Level2_head1 Level2_head2 Level2_head3
ID                                             
S0000001    someValue    someValue    someValue
S0000002    someValue    someValue    someValue
S0000003    someValue    someValue    someValue
S0000004    someValue    someValue    someValue
S0000005    someValue    someValue    someValue

print df.index.name
ID

print df.index
Index([u'S0000001', u'S0000002', u'S0000003', u'S0000004', u'S0000005'], dtype='object', name=u'ID')

print df.index.to_series()
ID
S0000001    S0000001
S0000002    S0000002
S0000003    S0000003
S0000004    S0000004
S0000005    S0000005
Name: ID, dtype: object

#if you need reset index
print df.index.to_series().reset_index(drop=True)
0    S0000001
1    S0000002
2    S0000003
3    S0000004
4    S0000005
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

Or solution with `pd.Series`:

```
print pd.Series(df.index)
0    S0000001
1    S0000002
2    S0000003
3    S0000004
4    S0000005
Name: ID, dtype: object
```